# How can I manually install angular libraries and get all dependencies without using bower or npm?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm trying to import some data from an Excel spreadsheet into my angular app. I found the [following](http://brianhann.com/easily-import-spreadsheets-into-ui-grid/) that details importing them into UI-Grid and using xlsx.js which seems a great basis for me to start.

But I'm currently working behind a very strict corporate firewall and can't get either bower or npm to work.
I can just about get nuget working in Visual Studio by setting up a proxy, although even with that I can't download any of the packages that have a dependency on node.js such as any of the npm, bower, grunt packages.

I've managed to get Node.js installed by downloading it on my personal pc and transferring it via usb. But still can't get those nuget packages to install.
So I've tried running npm direct in the node.js instance I have successfully downloaded. Still no joy.

I've tried configuring the proxies in numerous different ways but I can't get npm, bower, git or grunt to work.

So I've downloaded the zips of ui-grid and xlsx from github and tried copying the files across to my project manually, but that doesn't seem to be working. 
Some of their dependencies aren't installed.

I'm new to angular, node, bower, npm so when things aren't totally simple I really need to be able to follow instructions, which in the angular world invariably seems to begin with installing via bower or npm, neither of which I seem to be able to do.

What I want to do is therefore determine the dependencies of the libraries I'm installing. I was guessing that package.json should show me the dependencies. So for xlsx it lists dependencies as :

```
"dependencies": { 
"ssf":"~0.8.1", 
"codepage":"~1.3.6", 
"cfb":">=0.10.0", 
"jszip":"2.4.0", 
"crc-32":"", 
"adler-32":"", 
"commander":""
```

},

I've also tried using cdn link as a temporary workaround as I'd read that somehow gets dependencies? but still not working:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js

So within the code, where it is erroring is an undefined object. Tracking that object back it is set as `_fs = require('f'+'s');`

But I can't find where require is defined, although from reading around I'm assuming its require.js, but that isn't listed as a dependency, so am I missing how to determine the dependencies?

Comment: You forgot to add your links

Comment: And if `git://` is blocked but `https://` is not you might give this command `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` a try

Comment: I suggest trying to overcome the proxy issue. We faced the same issue.
Have you checked out this [link](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)?
Also, if you're just starting with Angular, I suggest you look at [Angular 2](https://angular.io/) even though it's still in beta...

Comment: @Perspectivus - thanks - I'd already followed that link, plus instructions in numerous SO posts on topic. Think it's a bit more than just proxies as the issue here. Loads of sites and domains are blocked too for various reasons. Kind of given up on getting those proxies to work, hence trying to get to bottom of manual installs. Angular 2 great, but I'm pushing the boundaries here with Angular s it is, Beta software definitely no go, but thanks for pointer, will look into it at home for some other projects

Answer (score 1):

People downloaded libraries without npm and bower for decades. Just go to https://code.angularjs.org/ choose what you need and download.

Comment: Yes I'm sure they did, but before bower and npm they'd have stated the dependencies. Now all the instructions say use bower or npm. No mention of any dependencies. I've installed everything without them so far, but now falling foul of lack of documentation on what else is needed. Also - that link only points to angular - has nothing to do with the other libraries or am I missing something there?

Comment: Your question clearly states "How can I manually install angular libraries". This is the link for all angular libraries. Pick up version and download what you need.

Comment: Yeah, have installed the core angular stuff no problems. But that's not my problem. The Title has a limit on text - not sure how to describe libraries on github that are written in angular but aren't actually angular itself? Thought angular libraries was a short but clear way of describing them. The question itself quite clearly states I'm trying to install xlsx and ui-grid. Ui-grid used to be ngGrid - it's not "Angular" but it is an angular directive.